# How do I specify a different PIN than 0000 when pairing a bluetooth device on android

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I have a bluetooth speaker with default passkey 1111 rather than 0000.
I'm not able to connect to it using my android tablet because of this error:

> Couldn't pair with SP104B because of an incorrect PIN or passkey

How do I specify a different PIN than 0000 when pairing a bluetooth device on android 4.2.2?

Answer (score 2):

To fix your speaker problem - Go to `Settings > Bluetooth > Turn On` and wait for your list of devices to populate. Locate your speaker and Long Press it (press and hold) and then select `Un-pair`. You'll be free to attempt to pair it again with the proper PIN!

If your device isn't paired with the phone, but it's still not connecting, you can try clearing your Bluetooth cache. Turn off Bluetooth, then Go to `Settings > Applications > All > Bluetooth Share and tap "Force Stop," then "Clear Cache," then "Clear Data`. If the device was ever paired or a pairing ever failed, it may have stored those credentials regardless of success. This should give you a fresh chance at it.

As for why you can't specify what PIN your speaker provides your phone - it's because the default PIN is assigned to the device when it's made, and can't be changed by the average consumer. Most 'dumb' Bluetooth devices have no way of changing the PIN it comes with.

Comment: My speaker is not paired with my tablet and when I tap on it to pair, there is no prompt for PIN. Android just try to pair using default passkey 0000 and then I get the error.

Comment: @S.Yavari - Ah, I misinterpreted your question - I assumed it was already paired but no longer connecting. I've updated my answer with additional troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I Tried these steps but the problem is still exists and there is no prompt for PIN.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem. Had nothing to do with phone. Try holding down the power button on Bluetooth device when pairing to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem with `BOSE` Bluetooth hand set with android (Version 4.4) phone.

I followed below step and succeed.

```
 1. Hold down the paired devices and removed the already added item.
 2. Bluetooth off and then ON.
 3. Search for new pairing and start pair the device.
```

Success. 
`Note:` If above steps not work and restart OS of both devices.